# can't use php variable as recipient name or email using phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Something weird is going on and I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong. I will first show you what works (obviously mydomain.com is fictitious)

```
$mail->Username = 'info@mydomain.com'; 

$mail->setFrom('info@mydomain.com', 'info');
$mail->addAddress($email, $_POST['first_name']);
```

So, that works as expected. But that isn't how I want it to work. setFrom and addAddress need to be reversed. However when I do that it doesn't work and there is no error message.

```
$mail->Username = 'info@mydomain.com'; 

$mail->setFrom($email, $_POST['first_name']);
$mail->addAddress('info@mydomain.com', 'info');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error are you getting? Try turning on the phpmailer debugging.

Comment: Sending with someone else's email as a `from` address is generally going to wind up straight in the spam folder. Consider the `Reply-To` header instead.

Comment: That's the problem. I am not getting an error. I am using ajax/jquery. If I swap it to the way that I said works, then the success message displays and the form is hidden via jQuery. If I do it the way that doesn't work, the success message displays but the form does not disappear and the email is not sent.

Comment: Take a look at the AJAX response in your browser's network inspector. If it's acting differently (form not disappearing) then the response is presumably different in some way.

Comment: @ceejayoz, are you suggesting that I remove $mail->setFrom ?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm suggesting that using `$mail->setFrom()` to set the `From` address to something not on your server will generally land it in the spam folder. Look up SPF records for why.

Comment: @ceejayoz, the setFrom is meant to be the details of the user filling out the contact form

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, and doing that'll make it go to spam, because if I put in my email address as `example@gmail.com`, spam filters will (correctly) flag your server as not being in Gmail.com's SPF record as a valid server for that domain.

Comment: Again, the `From` address should be one your server is authorized via SPF to send for. You'd use the `Reply-To` header instead to make replies go to the person who filled out the form.

Comment: Okay, I removed this `$mail->setFrom($email, $_POST['first_name']);` and just used `$mail->addReplyTo($email, $_POST['first_name']);` instead but I get the same result

Comment: Like I said, examine the AJAX result. You said your JS isn't hiding the form, which means the AJAX result is different in some way. Figure out why.

Comment: @ceejayoz, the contents of the form are meant to be emailed to me and not to the user who filled out the form.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I am trying to figure it out by looking at the network tab in google chrome but not sure what I am actually looking for as I haven't done that before.

Comment: Turn your php error reporting on as well

Comment: @ceejayoz, I think I understand properly now. I had to set both setFrom and addAddress to my domain email and then addReplyTo to the users inputted email. That seems to have resolved my problem. Please could you post that in a separate answer so I can award you the accepted answer.

Comment: Let me guess - you're sending via gmail, which doesn't allow setting arbitrary From addresses. This is covered in the PHPMailer docs.